# Google Workspace Integration- share files between users for editing in real time

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am integrating Google workspace into my web application. The use case is  that my application users should be able to edit the excel sheet with in the web app. And also the user should be able to share these files with some other user with in the same enterprise and both the users should be able to edit the sheet parallel.

The problem here is that:

**Storage**:

- Since both the users should be able to edit the same sheet in real time where should I store the excel sheet. I can show the excel sheet in my application only after I upload it to some user account's google drive first. If I store it in one user Google drive then how can I give the permission to  second user to be able to edit the sheet. Does there exist any common storage plan or option?
- How can I make sure that the sheet I uploaded to the user's drive account is not visible to the user in own drive?

Common storage problem.